# classes only being removed on the first iterated elements in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have developed a modal script for my website, which activates and de-activates modals on a page.

The activating of modals works fine in itself. However, when it comes to de-activating them, it's a problem. The idea is that when a user presses `esc`, **all** modals currently activated on the page will close.

For some reason though, the `for` loop (which is supposed to iterate through **all** open modals), only iterates once.

This is an example of what two modals (and triggers) on the page would look like:

```
<!-- these triggers and modals will be de-activated !-->
<a class="trigger-active">Trigger 1</a>
<div class="modal-active">Modal 1</div>

<!-- these ones won't !-->
<a class="trigger-active">Trigger 2</a>
<div class="modal-active">Modal 2</div>
```

and here is my **JavaScript**:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var escape = false,
        activeTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName("trigger-active"),
        activeModal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-active");

    if("key" in e){
        escape = (e.key == "Escape" || e.key == "Esc");
    } else {
        escape = (evt.keyCode == 27);
    }

    if(escape){
        for(var i = 0; i < activeTrigger.length; i++){
            console.log("Trigger " + i);
            activeTrigger[i].className = activeTrigger[i].className.replace(triggerRegex, "");
        }
        for(i = 0; i < activeModal.length; i++){
            console.log("Modal " + i);
            activeModal[i].className = activeModal[i].className.replace(modalRegex, "");
        }
    }
}
```

If I check the `console` for the iteration counts, all I get is

```
Trigger 0
Modal 0
```

Instead of:

```
Trigger 0
Modal 0
Trigger 1
Modal 1
```

I've used `for` loops many times before, and this has never happened to me before, so all help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted to suggest the loop wouldn't process all the elements. This suggests a console error, or the DOM doesn't contain all the elements you think it does.

Comment: I've placed it all in a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded, function(){ ... });`, and the elements are definitely there, as they're not dynamically added through **JavaScript**. So, possibly a console error? But I don't see any.

Comment: Have you console.log'd the value of `activeTrigger` to check it contains all the elements you think it does? Always suspect your DOM selectors :)

Comment: @Utkanos yes, I did :) and as expected, it contained **all** of the active triggers. https://imgur.com/a/Bimhm

Comment: Then I'm stumped. Try to recreate the problem in a Fiddle.